# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a view that adds another view on top in this manner:

```
- (void)showAreaEditView {

    NSLog(@"SHOWING AREA EDITOR VIEW");

    if (self.thisAreaEditorView == nil) {

        // Create View
        AreaEditorView *tmpViewController = [[AreaEditorView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AreaEditorView" bundle:nil];
        self.thisAreaEditorView = tmpViewController;
        [tmpViewController release];

        // Hide the back button
        self.thisAreaEditorView.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    }

    self.thisAreaEditorView.myInspectionID = self.myInspectionID;
    self.thisAreaEditorView.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    self.thisAreaEditorView.loggedInGroup = loggedInGroup;

    // Slide view up

    [self.view addSubview:thisAreaEditorView.view];


    CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - thisAreaEditorView.view.frame.size.width/2,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height/2 - thisAreaEditorView.view.frame.size.height/2, 
                                 thisAreaEditorView.view.frame.size.width, 
                                 thisAreaEditorView.view.frame.size.height);

    CGRect startFrame = endFrame; // offscreen source

    // new view starts off bottom of screen
    startFrame.origin.y += self.view.frame.size.height;
    self.thisAreaEditorView.view.frame = startFrame;

    // start the slide up animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.6];   
    thisAreaEditorView.view.frame = endFrame; // slide in
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I'm sure you can just ignore the slide part, I feel the addSubview is relevant.

Then in thisAreaEditor I have the view with the table and buttons and such.  UITableView delegate/datasource is going to File's Owner as normal.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection returning %d", [tableData count]);
    [tableData count];

}
```

This function numberOfRowsInSection returns 4

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *thisText =  [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisText;

    NSLog(@"looking at cell %d text:%@", indexPath.row, thisText);

    return cell;

}
```

But cellForRowAtIndexPath never gets called.

I'm at a loss here, I have no idea how it can seem to work fine but one of the delegate functions simply not be called.

I have tried `[bigTable reloadData]` and so on, the table just never gets populated and no logs from the function output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have just edited this out, if so I'm sorry, but it looks like you forgot to return tableData's count.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection returning %d", [tableData count]);
    return [tableData count];
}
```

Comment: Oh my, you're right.  I was missing the `return` in `numberOfRowsInSection`.  Can't belive it was that simple, thank you!

Comment: im using a switch statement in `numberOfRowsInSection` to handle 8 different sections. and overlooked not including the word `return`. some problems can be so silly to solve.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're missing UITableViewDelegate.

If you're using Interface Builder, right click the table view outlet and drag both `delegate` and `datasource` to `File's Owner`.

And if not using Interface Builder add this where you init your tableView

```
bigTable.delegate = self;
bigTable.dataSource = self;
```

Remember to import the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols, just as Srikar says.

Hope this is to any help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is also not called when the tableview's height is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not set the tableView delegate as self or the datasource as self. Add this code & see if it works now -

```
[tableView setDelegate:self];
[tableView setDataSource:self];
```

Also in your header file inherit these delegates - `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

```
@interface yourViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately.  In `viewWillAppear` I call `populateTableData` function which triggers `[bigTable reloadData]` so  `titleForHeaderInSection` gets called (returning nothing), then `numberOfRowsInSection` (returns 4), then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a older link, but I wanted to update this with putting info on how I resolved this issue.
For me the issue was the Array to populate the table had 0 rows so cellForRowAtIndexPath was never called.
Make sure that the Array you are using to populate the table has data in it.